# How can I make my visual Java application copy itself to a custom dir?

Tags: java, jar, copy

Can someone give me a way for do this in Java?

I know the steps:

1. Get the jar file execution directory for obtain the .jar path.
2. Copy that .jar (using the obtained path) to a custom directory.

What I want is sample codes for doing this. Other posts here about the #1 step are confusing for me in some way, because refer to obtain a class directory, but my goal is to obtain the full and specific path to the .jar file that is running for copy it; and also talks about security concerns which I don't understand very well. Also the metoth in Java for copying files aren't clear for me. For that, I request code samples.

Also, there's a way for doing all this process if the .jar file is wrapped into a .exe file? Some comment in other post said "Nearly impossible", but for what reason it's impossible? And, is really impossible?

Answer (score 1):

Please note, that it is important, that the class (`YourMainClass` reference in the code), which runs the following code was loaded from the jar file, you want to copy:

```
String jarFilePath = YourMainClass.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI().getPath();
```

As you get jar-file path, you can [copy it](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.CopyOption...-) to a directory:

```
import static java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption.*;

Files.copy(source, target, REPLACE_EXISTING);
```

---

**UPDATE**

To avoid the `Illegal char <:> at index 2:` problem, reported in comments, instead of `FileSystems.getDefault().getPath()` call use `java.io.File` class to obtain `Path` object via `toPath()` method.

I've updated the code, and moved destination folder path from code to the application argument.

The complete code is below:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import static java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption.*;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;

public class JarFileCopyTester {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException, IOException {

        // checking for mandatory application argument
        if (args.length != 1) {
            System.out.println("Usage:\njava -jar JarFileCopyTester.jar <targetFolderPath>");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        // the destination folder path, without filename
        String destinationFolderPath = args[0];
        if (!destinationFolderPath.endsWith(File.separator)) {
            destinationFolderPath = destinationFolderPath + File.separator;
        }

        // getting the running jar file path    
        String jarFilePath = JarFileCopyTester.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI().getPath();

        // getting Path object related to the jarFilePath
        Path sourcePath = (new File(jarFilePath)).toPath();

        System.out.println("sourcePath: " + sourcePath);

        // getting jar file name only, to compose dest file path
        Path jarFileNameOnly = sourcePath.getFileName();

        // adding filename to the destination folder path
        String destinationFilePath = destinationFolderPath + jarFileNameOnly.toString();

        // composing the Path object for the destination file path
        Path destPath =(new File(destinationFilePath)).toPath();

        System.out.println("destination path: "  + destPath);

        // copying the file
        Files.copy(sourcePath, destPath, REPLACE_EXISTING);
    }
}
```

to run the jar file, call the command:

Windows:

```
java -jar JarFileCopyTester.jar c:\myFolder1\myFolder2
```

Linux:

```
java -jar JarFileCopyTester.jar /home/username/
```

Comment: Some posts refer that `toURI()` may cause problems if there's non-english characters involving in the path. How can I handle that situation?

Comment: @FiroKun just checked it with a folder with russian name, the code works ok (Ubuntu Linux, java 1.8.0_77). Do you have any problems with this code ?

Comment: @FiroKun check this image: http://i.imgur.com/5EzFQNm.jpg  I've created a folder `тестовая папка` (means `test folder`), and ran this code in that folder. All worked fine.

Comment: Ok. I'm having troubles in the `Files.copy()` operation, it says that `source` and `target` must be `Path` objects, but I had the .jar path into a `String`. How can I convert that `String` in a `Path` object for use in the copy operation?

Comment: @FiroKun please wait couple minutes, I will update my answer shortly.

Comment: @FiroKun I have updated my answer with full working example. Check it please.

Comment: Thanks for the complete sample! But I'm having the following error: `java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <:> at index 2: /C:/Users/Alvaro/Documents/NetBeansProjects/WiFiMannager/build/classes/`, a problem with `:` of the hdd letter in the path while I attempt to build a `Path` objetc from the `String`. I'm working in Windows, btw.

Comment: @FiroKun I have updated my answer with new code. It works in windows and in linux.

Comment: Doesn't work. In the destination folder only a folder `class` is created, but no `.jar` file is copied. My final goal is, for example, having a `.jar` file in the desktop, and when I execute it, made a copy of that same `.jar` file in `C:` or other arbitrary location. I've debugged the code, and saw that `sourcePath.getFileName()` doesn't give the `.jar` file name, and `jarFilePath` and `sourcePath` doesn't contain any `.jar` file name at the end of the path.

Comment: @FiroKun Looks like you ran your code from IDE. Don't do that. It is supposed to copy jar file, but when you run your code from IDE, there is no jar file created yet. Do the following: step 1. Create jar file.  step 2. Run this jar file as it is shown in my answer. Don't use your IDE.